# photo lens unity in 17.10

Tags: 17.10, photo

What is photo lens unity in 17.10 and why is that whenever I try to run it in my 17.10 I get the message  "desktop file didn't specify exec field" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Photos lens for Unity*" (`unity-lens-photos`) is package containing photos scopes which allow Unity to search for local and online photos.

I reckon you have upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 from an older release of Ubuntu (with Unity) and thus the package is (still somehow) installed in your system.

Ubuntu 17.10 has GNOME shell, not Unity. Unless you have installed (or still have) Unity and are planning to use it, you can safely remove this package as it won't be useful with GNOME. You can remove it by running

```
sudo apt remove unity-lens-photos
```